# When running test in Visual Studio I get OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The executeScript command returned an unexpected error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, appium, appium-ios, browserstack

I am running Appium with NUnit Framework and a BrowserStack cloud. When I run iOS the test fails in Visual Studio but passes in the cloud. When I debug it passes but when I run the test regularly it fails with the executeScript issue. The change happened after I upgraded the dotnet version to the newest RC. The code appears to work as it passes in BrowserStack so I think its something to do with Visual Studio setup maybe? I am running Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.6.6